# Telnet - EventMachine, Theaded?

Tags: ruby, multithreading, telnet, eventmachine

I have a project where I need to update multiple thousands of devices with a series of commands via telnet. The commands will not brick or cause the device to go offline (login, apply commands, logout).

I use snmp4em extensively where SNMP is applicable. A blocking approach here would take forever.

I am not well versed with Threading, EventMachine (at its core), etc., to attempt to approach this from scratch.

I have been looking at em-simple_telnet.  It appears to have the functionality I need, my problem is the error coding.  If a host isn't reachable or fails login, it throws an error at the top-most level of the code (`EventMachine.run do`), which I've found difficult to `rescue`.

Maybe I'm having a blond-moment but I'm not seeing the solution.  The following code works as long as there is no failure.

```
require 'em-simple_telnet'

File.delete('/tmp/telnetDebug.log') if File.exists?('/tmp/telnetDebug.log')

begin
  EventMachine.run do

    ['device1', 'device2_will_fail', 'device3'].each do |h|
      opts = {
        host: h,
        username: "user",
        password: "pass",
        binmode: true,
        telnetmode: true,
        login_prompt: /[$%#:>]\s\z/n,
        password_prompt: /[$%#:>]\s\z/n,
        prompt: /[$%#:>]\s?\z/n,
        output_log: "/tmp/telnetDebug.log",
      }

      EM::P::SimpleTelnet.new(opts) do |host|
        # already logged in
        puts "Connected"
        puts host.cmd('cmd1') { |c| puts c }
        puts host.cmd('cmd2') { |c| puts c }
        puts host.cmd("exit") { |c| puts c }
      end
    end

  end
rescue Exception => e
  puts e.inspect
end


me@WorkStation:~/ruby_workspace/modem_updates$ ruby modem_update_em.rb
#<EventMachine::Protocols::SimpleTelnet::LoginFailed: Timed out while expecting some kind of prompt.>
```

I'm reaching out to those that would have experience in this area and could offer some possible solutions to my problem.  Can someone offer a suggestion as to how to recover from error (shown below)?  Or perhaps another approach?  Your expertise is most appreciated.

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to reinvent a wheel. Have you looked at [Puppet or similar solutions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Puppet_(software))? Discussing those is off-topic on Stack Overflow and such a discussion or further information should occur on one of the sibling sites, such as http://serverfault.com/search?q=puppet&s=6a2573db-1cbd-478d-8e89-8a9d03ad8cd0.

Comment: I certainly don't want to reinvent the wheel.  I have heard of Puppet.  Never used it and wasn't aware of it's use.  I'll take a look...  Thank you

Comment: I've taken a quick look at puppet and it does seem pretty heavy for my needs.  These are not cisco devices but login behaves line one.  SSH isn't an option.  I'm simply trying to hasten the time it'll take to send a few commands to each (8000+) devices.

Comment: We do similar things where I work. There are a continuing list of issues that'll crop up as you try to talk to devices with command-lines. While existing tools might seem overkill, they're usually that way because they've run into the dragons waiting for you and have coded in solutions. You don't have to use the full feature set, only enough to satisfy the need. I'd recommend looking at chef and the others too as they all have their niches. Good luck.

Comment: I was hoping to leverage what I already know, or mostly know vs having to install and learn an entirely new infrastructure.  This project I'm working on isn't going to be an ongoing thing.  I just need a quick and dirty approach.  I thank you for your input...